# Como impedir que links do AdSense abram em nova aba

Tags: javascript, html5, flash, google-adsense

Existe algum método de impedir que meu site abra links em nova aba e fazê-los abrir na mesma? E o contrário? Obrigado.

Edit: Uso o Google Adsense. Alguns anúncios abrem na mesma aba, outros abrem uma nova aba. Queria bloquear que abrissem em nova aba.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, para abrir sempre na mesma aba, utilize o atributo `_self`, e para abrir sempre outra aba, o atributo `_blank`.

Por exemplo:

```
<a href="http://www.seusite.com" target="_blank">Abre em outra página</a>

<a href="http://www.seusite.com" target="_self">Abre na mesma página</a>
```

Edit: Dá uma olhada [nesta página](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/google_adsense_ads_open_in_new_window/), principalmente nos comentários, onde tem inclusive o link para uma [possível solução](http://imtips.co/how-to-open-adsense-in-new-window-safely.html). Mas já adianto que, segundo consta ali, modificar o comportamento do google ad sense pode ferir os termos de serviço, e você pode inclusive ser expulso do sistema.

Comment: Mas onde a pessoa clica no meu site está em flash, e já está programado para abrir em nova aba.

Comment: Não existe nenhum outro método sem ser atributo? Algo que afete o site inteiro?

Comment: Ah, neste caso eu não sei, acho que vc tem que configurar isso no próprio flash, mas pode ser que exista mesmo algo em js... Sugiro que edite a pergunta pra incluir mais detalhes, principalmente informando que o site está em flash...

Comment: O site não está em flash. É porque tem anúncios do Google Adsense. Alguns abrem em nova aba, outros não.

Comment: Editei a resposta, mas acho que não tenho boas notícias. :)

Comment: Se ainda nao conhece as regras, leia antes de fazer kaka